# Emulate Adobe Acrobats "Print to PDF" using Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I am writing a batch file to emulate a manual task of opening each PDF in a folder with Acrobat, and printing to PDF.

The goal of the manual task is to get the uniform 8-1/2 x 11 page size, and the flattened, compressed file sizes.

What I have written so far does an okay job, but on some larger PDFs, the results of the script are much larger than the Print to PDF results.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 ECHO attempting compression subroutine... >>"%log%"
 cd %GS_DIR%

gswin64c.exe ^
  -o "%drive%%filepath%%name%-c.pdf"       ^
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite                        ^
  -sPAPERSIZE=letter                       ^
  -dFitPage                                ^
  -dCompressPages=true                     ^
  -dCompressFonts=true                     ^
  -dDownsampleColorImages=true             ^
  -dDownsampleGrayImages=true              ^
  -dDownsampleMonoImages=true              ^
  -dColorImageResolution=300               ^
  -dGrayImageResolution=300                ^
  -dMonoImageResolution=300                ^
  -dColorImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0      ^
  -dGrayImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0       ^
  -dMonoImageDownsampleThreshold=1.0       ^
  -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray          ^
  -dColorConversionStrategy=/Gray          ^
  -dColorConversionStrategyForImages=/Gray ^
  -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4                 ^
  -dEmbedAllFonts=false                    ^
  -c ".setpdfwrite <</AlwaysEmbed [ ] /NeverEmbed [/Courier /Courier-Bold /Courier-Oblique /Courier-BoldOblique /Helvetica /Helvetica-Bold /Helvetica-Oblique /Helvetica-BoldOblique /Times-Roman /Times-Bold /Times-Italic /Times-BoldItalic /Symbol /ZapfDingbats] /ColorImageFilter /DCTEncode /GrayImageFilter /DCTEncode /MonoImageFilter /CCITTFaxEncode /OutputICCProfile (None)>> setdistillerparams" ^
  -f %fullpath%

ECHO compression complete, cleaning up files... >>"%log%"
```

I think the issue may be font related, but I am unsure how to fix it, Here is a common message from one of the files while ghost script runs:

```
Can't find (or can't open) font file %rom%Resource/Font/ArialMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file ArialMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file %rom%Resource/Font/ArialMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file ArialMT.
Querying operating system for font files...
Didn't find this font on the system!
Substituting font Helvetica for ArialMT.
Loading NimbusSanL-Reg font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSanL-Reg... 4826216 3500251 7703168 6115407 3 done.
Can't find (or can't open) font file %rom%Resource/Font/Arial-BoldMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file Arial-BoldMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file %rom%Resource/Font/Arial-BoldMT.
Can't find (or can't open) font file Arial-BoldMT.
Didn't find this font on the system!
Substituting font Helvetica-Bold for Arial-BoldMT.
Loading NimbusSanL-Bol font from %rom%Resource/Font/NimbusSanL-Bol... 5025328 3699533 7797072 6194808 3 done.
```

Any ideas on better parameters to emulate the Print-To-PDF behavior?

Comment: Don't set any parameters. The defaults are chosen to be sane, adding any thing else forces the code to make additional checks and potentially do extra work (such as downsampling images) which takes time. Of course, since you appear to be doing this to reduce file size, perhaps that's an important parameter for you, but then its going to cost you performance....

Comment: You are also (for example) converting everything to gray, so that means inspecting and altering every single pixel of every image, is it really surprising that this is slow ?

Comment: Printing a PDF to PDF, otherwise known as "refrying" is probably the worst way to accomplish your goal. You're far better off using a real PDF API for this.

Comment: He isn't really printing it, he's running it through a PDF interpreter, with a bunch of commands to alter aspects of the content, and then emitting it as a PDF. While I don't particularly think its a good idea, its not really 'printing'.

Comment: In order to have any clue why the file is bigger than 'print to PDF' (are you really printing from Acrobat to a virtual printer ?) We'd need to know an awful lot more about how your 'print to PDF' is configured and would need at the very least an example problem file to look at.

Comment: **Hi KenS**, Thank you for your feedback. My problem isn't performance, but rather the final file size too large, compared to using adobe's print-to-pdf.

**Hi Joel**, Yes, you are probably right, but I was looking at automating a monotonous manual daily task, into something a batch file could handle. I've read a lot of compression posts for ghostscript, and this was the closest I got to emulating the "resize and compress" results of print-to-pdf. So I wondering if I had configured GS wrong somehow or missed a parameter.